# How to return iterator type in MethodDeclaration class?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I have a function that receives a `MethodDeclaration`:

```
public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node){ }
```

I need to iterate through the tree (starting from `node`), so I declared:

```
Iterator<MethodDeclaration> itr;
```

in a for loop and used it like this:

```
for(Iterator<MethodDeclaration> itr = node; itr.hasNext();)
```

So my function looks something like this so far:

```
public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node)
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        for (Iterator<MethodDeclaration> itr = node; itr.hasNext();)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

The `itr` declaration and `itr.hasNext()` are working (eclipse identifies them). But the line `Iterator<MethodDeclaration> itr = node;` isn't. I obviously need to activate some method in `node` that returns `iterator` type. But I couldn't find any.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Does your `MethodDeclaration` implements `Iterator`? If not, you can not use iterator. You may need to use while to loop through your nodes.

Comment: What are you trying to iterate over?

Answer (score 0):

`node` is a single `MethodDeclaration` object, I don't think there is a way to get an `iterator` of `MethodDeclaration`s from a `MethodDeclaration itself.

So, looks like you only need to work with the `node` object you are receiving... as the Iterator is being iterated outside the `visit` method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to iterate over each statement of the method body, you can do the following:

```
MethodDeclaration node;
//Get node from somewhere

Block methodBody=node.getBody(); // getBody returns body of code as a Block 
for(Object a: methodBody.statements()){ //Block.statements returns a list of statements. 
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

You can do the same thing using an iterator on the list returned by Block.statements(). Hope this helps.